# How to implement MouseListener into the controller in Java

Tags: java, mouselistener

I've been working on a Tic tac toe program using Model View Control design. I'm trying to add a mouse listener to the view in my controller. What is the best way to do this?

My controller looks something like this.

```
public class TicTacToeViewController implements MouseListener{

TicTacToeView view;
TicTacToeModel model;
Color oColor=Color.BLUE, xColor=Color.RED;

public TicTacToeViewController(TicTacToeView view, TicTacToeModel model) { 

  this.model = model;
  this.view = view;
 // this.view.addMouseListener(new TicTacToeViewController(view, model));
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  int xpos=e.getX()*3/view.getWidth();
  int ypos=e.getY()*3/view.getHeight();
  //System.out.println("Play "+xpos+","+ypos);
  play(xpos,ypos);
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Basically I can not get the cells of my tic tac toe program to be clickable.  I need help.

Thank you.

Comment: Set this controller as a mouse listener on the view, or component, of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, to add this controller's MouseListener into the views assuming there's a addMouseListener Method in the views class is by passing in "this".

```
this.view.addMouseListener(this);
```